# Downvote on closed questions

Tags: support, downvotes, closed-questions

My question is closed as off-topic. But still someone can downvote it.

Is it possible to downvote some closed questions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to down- (or indeed up-) vote a closed question.

The only questions you can't vote on are locked or deleted ones.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible to downvote closed questions.